# Use of "many good wishes 'to carry with you'"

Tags: idioms, literary-english

In "The Wonderful Wizard of Oz" there is two times this phrase: "many good wishes to carry with you":

- And the Winkies gave them three cheers and many good wishes to carry with them.
- But he at once unlocked their spectacles, which he put back into the green box, and gave them many good wishes to carry with them.

I think is not a so common phrase to listen to. Googling for [that](https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&q=%22good+wishes+to+carry+with%22+-oz+-baum+-wizard&oq=%22good+wishes+to+carry+with%22+-oz+-baum+-wizard&gs_l=hp.3...8922.11172.5.11395.8.8.0.0.0.0.214.1429.0j6j2.8.0.crnk_timediscounta..0.0.0..1.1.17.hp.2-RBCHG5EgE&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47883778,d.bGE&fp=a16347be1f9226b7&biw=1215&bih=909) it seems to be nowhere out of that book.
Are there some regions where is used or other similar expressions?
Of course I mean the second part 'to carry with you/him/them'

Comment: It's not a "regionalism" - it's more of a quirky literary device. Obviously you can't really "carry" good wishes anywhere (except figuratively, in your memory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Good Wishes" is reasonably common, though the more common construction would be if someone "wishes you well" (or other, similar conjugations), before you set off on a journey.

The construction of "good wishes to carry with you" is peculiar to Baum -  or at least, not an idiom of any sort. But it's well rooted in other existing phrases, such as the aforementioned "to wish well", "best wishes", etc. etc.

All carry roughly the same connotation, of a farewell accompanied by an expression of hope for good fortune for the person from whom you are departing (or who is departing from you).